# Finding missing fields by comparing 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this:

```
GroupID    Room
    10        A
    10        B
    10        C
    20        A
    20        C
    20        D
    30        A  
    30        B
    30        C
```

On 1st column there're multiple groups and they been assigned rooms. So group 10 has A, B, C rooms assigned to it.

Now i want to find groups that are missing the same room compared to group 10.

So from above example it should pick Group ID = 20 & Room = B. Like that it should list all group IDs and the missing room.

All i could do so far is,

```
select GroupID, Count(*)
from GroupRooms
group by GroupID;
```

This currently only returns something like this,

```
GroupID         Count(*)
  10              3
  20              3
  30              3
```

Comment: The requirement is not clear. Is GroupID = 10 special in some way, and you need - for each other GroupID - to find which "rooms" that are assigned to 10 are not also assigned to these other groups? If you mean something **different** from that, it's not clear what you need.

Comment: Your're right. 10 is special and need to make sure that all other groups also have same rooms. So from above table, the new query should return - GroupID = 20 & Room = B. Like that, it should list all GroupIDs & Rooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by generating all the rows for each group for all the rooms in group 10.  Then use a `left join` to determine which actually exist:

```
select g.groupId, t10.room
from t t10 cross join
     (select distinct GroupId from t) g left join
     t     
     on t.groupId = g.groupId and t.room = t10.room 
where t10.GroupId = 10 and t.room is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM GroupRooms
Where GroupID <> 10 AND Room NOT IN (SELECT Room from GroupRooms where GroupID = 10)
```

If I understood your question correctly, this should work. Find all rooms unused by other IDs and used by Id=10

Comment: MordenoYes, this gives me GroupID = 20 & Room = D. Can it say Room = B. Because that's the room that's missing from GroupID - 10.

Comment: You can try Gordon ''s answer. Just replace 't' with your table name. It displays the correct values. @DonK